# SendMessageCallback usage example

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644951%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I v been searching everywhere but cant find a single working thing in c on how this could be done. There seems to be several calls which totally confused me. Perhaps someone can put just a small example on how to declare this callback then post message to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you are perfectly comfortable with plain ol' `SendMessage`. The step from there to `SendMessageCallback` is not that long.

First, look at

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(__in  HWND hWnd,
                           __in  UINT Msg,
                           __in  WPARAM wParam,
                           __in  LPARAM lParam);
```

Then look at

```
BOOL WINAPI SendMessageCallback(__in  HWND hWnd,
                                __in  UINT Msg,
                                __in  WPARAM wParam,
                                __in  LPARAM lParam,
                                __in  SENDASYNCPROC lpCallBack,
                                __in  ULONG_PTR dwData);
```

It's glaringly obvious that the differing parts are the `SENDASYNCPROC` and `ULONG_PTR` parameters of `SendMessageCallback`.

The `lpCallBack` up there is the name of a callback of yours that will be called by the OS when the `hWnd` window procedure returns after handling the message `Msg` you sent to it.

The type of `lpCallBack` is `SENDASYNCPROC`, which is declared as

```
VOID CALLBACK SendAsyncProc(__in  HWND hwnd,
                            __in  UINT uMsg,
                            __in  ULONG_PTR dwData,
                            __in  LRESULT lResult);
```

The `dwData` up there is any kind of data you want to use inside your callback, whenever it gets called. This is usually a pointer to complex data, like a struct or C++ class. In that case the lifetime of the memory must be considered carefully, so that it's valid when the callback is called. The `dwData` can also be just the simple integer data it looks like.

Bringing it all together, then. In your code you call `SendMessageCallback` like this (error checking omitted for readability):

```
SendMessageCallback(hWnd, WM_FOO, 0, 0, MySendAsyncProc, (ULONG_PTR)myData);
```

But, hmmm, since this is an exercise, let's assume that myData is just 0:

```
SendMessageCallback(hWnd, WM_FOO, 0, 0, MySendAsyncProc, 0);
```

That means you have declared a callback `MySendAsyncProc`:

```
VOID CALLBACK MySendAsyncProc(__in  HWND hwnd,
                              __in  UINT uMsg,
                              __in  ULONG_PTR dwData,  // This is *the* 0
                              __in  LRESULT lResult)   // The result from the callee
{
    // Whohoo! It called me back!
}
```

And that callback will be called when your `WM_FOO` message has been handled.

That pretty much sums it up.

Comment: thanks for great effort and you did sum it up well but confusing part for me is declaring that callback. Isnt the declaration you put there just how its declared in winapi defs? I have a callback that resides as pointer in another language that i need to pass to dll file which sends the message to my app(that passes callback pointer) Btw in this language i cannot declare MySendAsyncProc as its not part of its language(autoit). Also i need to send this message and have this callback called instantly without waiting for other messages to finish. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Marko29: It's difficult to say anything without seeing some actual code. Also, you want the callback to be called immediately, but *you* cannot decide when the callback is called back. That's sort of in its definition. You have no control over what's happening over in the other window's window procedure.

Comment: Well at least i accept this for great explanation, it doesnt solve my problems though but that aint your fault.